# Try-catch block in Kotlin -- what to return

Tags: java, kotlin, return, try-catch, stripe-payments

```
fun cancelSubscription(cancelStripeSubscription: CancelStripeSubscription): Subscription {
        Stripe.apiKey = testApiKey
        try {
            val sub = Subscription.retrieve("superSecret")
            return sub.cancel(null)
        } catch (e: StripeException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

`Background`:

Kotlin newbie here trying to integrate Stripe Billing into a Kotlin app.

`Problem`:

As `e.printStackTrace()` is of type `Unit` according to Kotlin, I see an error that says `A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body.({...})`.

How can I make this work?

**Edit**: I am using `stripe-java` here..

Comment: The method must return a `Subscription`, but you only do that inside the `try`. If an exception is thrown then what is the method supposed to return?. Looks like it tries to return the result of `printStackTrace`, which is `Unit` not a `Subscription`. There are at least two solutions: (1) Let the exception bubble up rather than catching it, or (2) make the return type nullable and return null when an exception is thrown. Or make the return type some kind of optional and return an empty value when an exception is thrown.

Comment: I thought about making it nullable but if I make the return type nullable, won't it throw a NullPointerException when it actually throws an error? Also, what exactly do you mean by `let the exception bubble up`?

Comment: Whether or not returning null is acceptable depends entirely on what the code calling this method does with the return value.  Kotlin has lots of ways to safeguard against nulls.  As for letting the exception bubble up, @Slaw meant to not catch the exception at all.  That way, whatever is calling this function can deal with it, instead.  Or whatever calls _that_ function.  The exception will "bubble up" through the call stack until it hits a try/catch block.

Comment: I think I'm gonna go with Bubbling. 
Thanks, @Slaw and @Jordan!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a function with a return type of `Subscription`. This means all possible code paths in the function must end up returning a `Subscription` or throwing an exception. As you currently have it, your code only returns in the `try` block. This is a problem; if an exception is thrown it moves into the `catch` block which has no return statements, nor are there any return statements after the `catch` block. This means there's a code path that results in no return—thus the error.

There are at least two solutions to this error:

1. Don't catch the exception; just let it bubble up out of the method to the caller.

   ```
   fun cancelSubscription(cancelStripeSubscription: CancelStripeSubscription): Subscription =
        Subscription.retrieve("superSecret").cancel(null)
   ```
2. Make the return type nullable and return null if an exception is thrown.

   ```
   fun cancelSubscription(cancelStripeSubscription: CancelStripeSubscription): Subscription? =
       try {
           Subscription.retrieve("superSecret").cancel(null)
       } catch (ex: StripeException) {
           null
       }
   ```

   > I thought about making it nullable but if I make the return type nullable, won't it throw a NullPointerException when it actually throws an error?

   The function itself won't throw an NPE, no. And since the return type is now nullable Kotlin will force you to handle that when you try to use the result. For more information, see [Null Safety - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html).

Answer (score 2):

Your function `cancelSubscription` must return a subscription or null
or there is an exception is does not do this so it's not valid

Better explained in the comment by Slaw, which it did not show me before I posted :/